# Mixpanel on instapage : mixpanel.people.set not working

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

I am using Mixpanel combined with Instapage. I aim to link an email adress to a user.

From what I get : 
1) The user is coming to my website and get a distinct ID
2) I need to 1 call mixpanel.alias + mixpanel.identify
3) I link the variable to the user using mixpanel.people.set

I added the mixpanel snippet and this script but it is not working. Any idea why ?

Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    var email = document.getElementById('4b8da538419309e7319a12be231f7456-1');
});


mixpanel.alias('email')
mixpanel.identify('email');
mixpanel.people.set({
"$email": email
});

</Script>
```

As a reference : https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/creating-a-profile

EDIT : Working Code :

```
$('form.email-form').submit(function() {
    mixpanel.identify($('#REPLACE_WITH_ID').val());
    mixpanel.people.set({
         "$email" : $('#REPLACE_WITH_ID').val()
    });
});
```

If needed add alias (I didn't need it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure you have added mixpanel library before the script above is executed. You can check that by console log the mixpanel object.
`console.log(mixpanel)`
And second thing is you are doing wrong in above code.

```
    $('#myForm').submit(function() {
        var email = document.getElementById('4b8da538419309e7319a12be231f7456-1');
        mixpanel.alias(email);
        mixpanel.identify(email); // or you can also do mixpanel.identify() only;
        mixpanel.people.set({
            "$email": email
        });
    });
```